# Multiple tables from two database in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in Mysql db, table 1

```
serial      Remark   
-------------------
1           programming in c++ 
2           OOPS using java
```

and table 2

```
Name      date         code    serial
-------------------------------------
Jack     2014-10-07    c++        1
Jill     2014-10-07    c++        1 
Moos     2014-10-07    c++        1
Jack     2014-10-08    java       2
Jill     2014-10-08    java       2
```

I want to generate multiple table using php in HTML,

1.Students in Programming in c++ are

```
Name      date       
-------------------
Jack     2014-10-07
Jill     2014-10-07
Moos     2014-10-07
```

2.Students in OOPS using java

```
Name      date       
-------------------
Jack     2014-10-08
Jill     2014-10-08
```

Can someone suggest the query?

Comment: What is the importance of table table 1 here? missing anything?

Comment: Serial no in table 1 has the remark but table two has course code.. serial number maps them

Comment: Using PHP in HTML ? suggest the query ? Sounds like a simple SELECT query .

Comment: Would it be possible to loop through so that the tables are generated for all the remarks?

Answer (score 0):

Query for case 1:

```
SELECT name, date from table2 inner join table1 on table2.serial = table1.serial where Remark='programming in c++'
```

Query for case 2:

```
SELECT name, date from table2 inner join table1 on table2.serial = table1.serial where Remark='OOPS using java'
```

or,

Another way:

Query for case 1:

```
SELECT name, date from table2, table1 where table2.serial = table1.serial and Remark='programming in c++'
```

Query for case 2:

```
SELECT name, date from table2, table1 where table2.serial = table1.serial and Remark='OOPS using java'
```

Comment: Would it be possible to loop through to generate tables instead of hardcoding. The entries in table1 are dynamically added

Comment: Yes, offcourse. refer this, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php